# Swipe through Gallery

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, extjs

I am creating an applilcation where I need to swipe through images in my gallery. I am using Sencha Touch for the same. It allows me to swipe through the images smoothly but I need a header that keeps a count of which image I am in. For eg: 1/5, 2/5 and so on.

Any idea how do i do that???

I would appreciate the code being in javascript and css specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a TextView and Gallery in your XML layout as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

    <Gallery android:id="@+id/gal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spacing="10px" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In Java file, before `onCreate()` method

```
TextView textView;
Gallery gallery;
```

Find the TextView as below

```
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
txtview.setText("1/"+count); // count is a variable which contains total no.of items in gallery
// Initially the item in Gallery is 1st one so, i took "1/"
```

Next, Gallery as below

```
gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gal);
```

I think you know how to set Adapter to Gallery, so not explaining that here.

In `onCreate()` method of your activity, write below code

```
    gallery.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {             
            int position = gallery.getSelectedItemPosition();
            txtview.setText(""+(position+1)+"/"+count);
            return false;
        }            
    });
```

The above code will display the position of Gallery Item when you swipe the Galley.

```
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                textView .setText(""+(position+1)+"/"+count);
            }
        });
```

The above code will display the position of Gallery Item when you click an item in the Galley.

I hope you will understand this, if any doubts feel free to ask me.

Comment: i appreciate it. thanks a lot. since i need it for android, i will try this out. But i am workin on cross platform applications, so i would prefer a solution in javascript.

Comment: Sorry i can't help you if you require same thing with JavaScript, coz i don't know JavaScript :-)

Comment: Hi Yugandhar...I am working on a similar app..a small clarification. By Adapter do you mean an array containing the list drawables ? For eg. int[] backGroundImages = {R.drawable.1,R.drawable.2,R.drawable.3}

Comment: not exactly array of drawables, you have to extend an Adapter Class (e.g., BaseAdapter) which internally use this array to display items. [Check this link you will get an idea](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-imageview-example)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this library,
[Jquery Touchwipe](http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library)

It works on Android

Comment: well,i am particular about the code being in JAVASCRIPT is because jquery has its own css and it over rides my css files. In addition, it is not compatible if I try to use the same code for IOS application.